# How to change a variable (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, boolean

I want to change values in the table from True, false To>>> Yes, No
,honesty I'm confused

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjyC9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWk7H.png)

Comment: You want a **dropdown** with Yes or No. Or you want a text?

Comment: I want text,  thank for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select list for this.

Edit like this your model:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : BaseCEViewModel
{
    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        BoolList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        BoolList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Yes",
            Value = "true"
        });
        BoolList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "No",
            Value = "false"
        });
        SelectedBools = new List<bool>();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> BoolList { get; set; }
    public List<bool> SelectedBools { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use a dropdownlist in your page, if you give same name to your dropdowns, values will add the SelectedBools Variable.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedBools", Model.BoolList, new { @class = "form-control select2", placeholder = "...Select..." })
```

Answer (score 0):

As we clarify that you want **text** not a **dropdown** in your `view`

Don't use `Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Active)`

Try using `if`

**Note:** As you specify the variable to accepts `null` value. First check for `null` then use `if` statement

`View`

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            if(item.Active != null)
            {
                if(Convert.ToBoolean(item.Active))
                {
                    <p>Yes</p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>No</p>
                }
            }
        </td>
        <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
}
```